# How to convert number to zero padding format in vsc?

Tags: visual-studio-code, padding, digits

I'm using vsc and I want to convert any number found to fixed 4 digits length using zero padding . For example :
2 -> 0002
99 -> 0099

Can I use find and replace ? or any extension ?

Thanks

Comment: VSC is an IDE, that you use to write code in various languages. It can't do anything to convert anything; that is done in the programming language you're using. As you added no tag for that language, your question can't be answered.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the numbers in a file you can use the extension I wrote [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen)

- open find: `Ctrl+F`
- enable regex search: `.*` button
- search for: `\d+`
- select all (with focus in find dialog): `Alt+Enter`
- execute command: **Generate text based on Regular Expression (regex)**
- Use match regex: `(.*)`
- Use generator regex: `{{N[1]:size(4)}}`
- Accept with `Return` if you see what you like or `Escape`

Answer (score 0):

Very easy to do with an extension I authored, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform).

Make this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`):

```json
{
  "key": "alt+p",                    // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "\\b(\\d{1,4})\\b",
    "isRegex": true,

    "replace": [            // replace with some javascript computation
      "$${",

          // $1 is the first capture group from the find regex
        "return '$1'.padStart(4, '0');",

      "}$$",
    ],

    "postCommands": "cancelSelection",
  }
}
```

The `"find": "\\b(\\d{1,4})\\b",` assumes your numbers are not within other text, like `blah123blah`.

If you want to handle the `blah123blah` case -> `blah0123blah`, then use the simple:

`"find": "(\\d+)",`

Demo using the simple `"find": "(\\d+)",` version:

[image: demo: replace numbers with padStarted zeros]